# SQL Server: count request optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, bigdata

I'm looking for a solution to optimize a select query that I'm running on some big tables (more than 100M items per table), here is the current solution I'm using, it takes more than 40min!!

```
SELECT Count(a.id) 
FROM   tablea a 
       JOIN tableb b 
         ON a.ref_xid = b.xid 
            AND a.ref_yid = b.yid 
WHERE  ( b.filtre = 1 
          OR b.filtre = 7 ) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                       FROM   tablec 
                       WHERE  xid = a.xid 
                              AND yid = a.yid);
```

Comment: indexes. indexes. indexes

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT Count(a.id) 
FROM tablea a JOIN
     tableb b 
     ON a.ref_xid = b.xid AND a.ref_yid = b.yid 
WHERE b.filtre IN (1, 7) AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM   tablec c
                  WHERE  c.xid = a.xid AND c.yid = a.yid
                 );
```

You want indexes on `tableb(filtre, xid, yid)`, `tablea(ref_xid, ref_yid)`, and `tablec(xid, yid)`.

Comment: I have already indexes on those columns but still not enough.

Comment: @Hisham . . . You have exactly the three indexes specified, with 3 columns, columns, and 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the query that's the problem here, it's the amount of I/O the machine has to go through.

```
SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM tablea a 
  JOIN tableb b 
    ON b.xid = a.ref_xid 
   AND b.yid = a.ref_yid
   AND b.filtre IN (1, 7) 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM tablec c
                    WHERE c.xid = a.xid 
                      AND c.yid = a.yid);
```

To limit this you should

- Add (relevant) indexes to the tables as to make sure you only need to run through the records that are needed
- Add 'covering' indexes to make sure that when the relevant entry-points in the indexes are found, they server doesn't need to go back to the records in the table in order to figure out some other field that's needed but is not included in the index

As for the example you gave I'd say you need the following indexes for optimal performance FOR THIS QUERY:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_filtre ON tableb (filtre) INCLUDE (xid, yid)
CREATE INDEX idx_ids    ON tablec (xid, yid)
CREATE INDEX idx_refids ON tablea (ref_xid, ref_yid) INCLUDE (xid, yid)
```

(I'm assuming all tables already have a clustered PK on the `id` field)

PS: The query-execution plan is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers and suggestions, final solution used was temporary tables, each time by applying one filter only. 5 tables were needed to do this, but final results are much better. I can consider question closed from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution that works was to use temporary tables and divide the request on 2 steps. 
A first one with only data preparation in the temporary tables and a second to process the temporary tables and apply the changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use temp tebles:

```
;
WITH    q1
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     tableB b
               WHERE    b.filtre = 1
                        OR b.filtre = 7
             ),
        q2
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     tableA a
               WHERE    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id
                                     FROM   tableC
                                     WHERE  xid = a.xid
                                            AND yid = a.yid )
             )
    SELECT  COUNT(a.id)
    FROM    tableA a
            JOIN tableB b ON a.ref_xid = b.xid
                             AND a.ref_yid = b.yid
```

Comment: you wan to write this?  `SELECT  COUNT(a.id)
    FROM    q2 a
            JOIN q1 b ON a.ref_xid = b.xid
                             AND a.ref_yid = b.yid`  but is it better to use COUNt(a.id) or Count(*)?

Comment: Why do you suggest to use temp-tables and then show an example with a CTE? CTE's are by far and large NO temp-tables but simply a different syntax for subqueries.

Comment: It's better we restrict our data that will be joined together to optimize query. So I use 'CTE' to do that. Here main cost is on join and at second level count() has high cost.